# Date function is not working with Mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

In command prompt of mysql 5.1 I am not able to use Date function.It tells syntax error. Can any buddy help me to solve this issue. In my local system where mysql version is `5.0` same command is working fine...!

I am confused what could be wrong with `mysql 5.1.39` Is there any setting in `my.cnf` for date support.

```
SELECT date('2012-03-01 03:15:00')
```

Above command is giving error:

```
MySQL said:  
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('2012-03-01 03:15:00')' at line 1
```

Above command is not working in `mysql 5.1.39` . Can you please help me regarding this?

Comment: I dont know - but could it be that date doesnt allow the time to be passed with the date? Which would make sense... Try using datetime instead

Comment: I am using datetime field in table. Problem is on `querying records`.

Comment: The error you posted has `near '(start_time) ='08:00:00')`. I see no where in your query any `(start_time)`. Please add the whole query, as you run it.

Comment: @ypercube , sorry error is updated now. I checked for another values before. thanks for pointing out  that.

Comment: @Ruby can you provide the complete query?

Comment: @ssmusoke, please find `SELECT date('2012-03-01 03:15:00')` is not wroking says error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) sql mode if it is set -

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
```

From the reference: ANSI_QUOTES - Treat ‘"’ as an identifier quote character (like the ‘`’ quote character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use ‘`’ to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled, you cannot use double quotes to quote literal strings, because it is interpreted as an identifier.

Change " quote with ', and execute -

```
SELECT DATE('2012-03-01 03:15:00');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Devart, I checked with both single quote, double quote, and '`' all. They all are not working ..   :(

Comment: How are you running this query? Try to execute it from mysql console.

Comment: I ran this query via both in console and in phpmyadmin gui :(

Comment: Maybe session parameters are different? Check this - SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

You can find the MySQL date functions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks for answer ssmusoke, I checked with both single quote, double quote that is not the issue there :(